# Magento 2 installation to use Extensions

Tags: magento2, extensions, installation, composer, git

i know is a bit boring ...

How I have to install magento 2 that I can simple use the Extension Manager?

If I try to use the Extension Manager I get these errors:

1. Check Updater Application Availability
2. Check Cron Scripts
3. Check Component Dependency
4. PHP Settings Check
5. PHP Extensions Check

Funny is if i check : For additional assistance, see [updater application help](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/prereq_updater.html) > devdocs.magento give me : Set up the updater (obsolete).

What I did to install:
Git clone -> Composer install etc.
Write permissions two user situation : the magento user is part of www-data and www-data is the owner of apache2, also.

Thanks to everyone who can give me a hand.